# ЧПУ. Что я не так настраиваю?

Tags: .htaccess, чпу

к примеру есть

> http://localhost/site/index.php?r=about

Надо так

> http://localhost/site/about

В htaccess вбила так:

```
deny from all
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/about$ /?r=about [NC,L]
```

Получила:

> http://localhost/site/?r=about

Ну что еще настроить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^site/([^/]*)$ /index.php?r=$1 [L]
```

Comment: не получается((((

Comment: @ЖуЖу, Это я что-то не так понял. Откуда у вас /site/ берется? Создан такой каталог на сервере? Или как?

Comment: @ЖуЖу, Вот сейчас окончательно запутали))). Давайте так. Вы напишете примерно в таком стиле: "Хочу из http://site.ru/index.php?r=about получить http://site.ru/about".))

Comment: @ЖуЖу, ??? Короче, если нужно из http://site.ru/index.php?r=about получить http://site.ru/about пишите как сказал @Gerome, если нужно из http://site.ru/index.php?r=about получить http://site.ru/site/about то сделайте как я ответил.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^about$ index.php?r=about [L]
```

Это только `about`.

Comment: ваш вариант не исправил положения почему-то

Comment: мадам, настройте `virtual hosts` и не мучайтесь, у вас что `Denwer`,`xampp` (и т.п.) или своя сборка?

Comment: @Gerome xampp. Настроила хосты. ну все равно с адресами та же история